# jquery full calendar horizontal drag and select multiple days

Tags: jquery

I have tried to implement horizontal drag selection in jquery full calendar but didn't get success.
Day wise vertical selection is possible but more than one day selection in single drag is not working.
Guys if your have any solution please suggest.

Below is my code for full calender:

```
$.createFullCalendarWithCurrentTime = function (selectCallback, eventsCallback,   
mouseOverCallback, options, eventRenderCallback, curTime) {

        calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            unselectAuto: false,
            header: { left: 'prev', center: 'title', right: 'next' },
            titleFormat: { week: "MMMM dd{ - dd, yyyy}" }, // Sep 7 - 13 2009 ,
            defaultView: "agendaWeek",
            // columnFormat: { month: 'ddd', week: 'ddd d/M', day: 'dddd d/M' },
            columnFormat: { week: 'ddd d'},
            eventBackgroundColor: options && options["eventBackgroundColor"] ?  
            options["eventBackgroundColor"] : "#FFEB00",
            eventBorderColor: "#FFEB00",
            eventTextColor: options && options["eventTextColor"] ? options["eventTextColor"] : 
            "#333333",
            axisFormat: 'h(:mm) tt',
            aspectRatio: 0.1,
            buttonText: { prev: '', next: '' },
            selectable: (selectCallback != null && $.isFunction(selectCallback) ? true : false),
            selectHelper: true,
            editable: false,
            allDaySlot: false,
            slotMinutes: slotMinute,
            minTime: minTimeNew,
            maxTime: maxTimeNew,
            firstDay: 1,
            eventMouseover: mouseOverCallback,
            viewDisplay: function () {
                // Create slots table only if not created 
            },
            select: selectCallback,
            events: eventsCallback,
            eventRender: eventRenderCallback
        }); 
        return calendar;
    };
      function slotBind(cells) {
            cells.click(slotClick)
            .mousedown(slotSelectionMousedown);
        }

     function slotSelectionMousedown(ev) {
            if (ev.which == 1 && opt('selectable')) { // ev.which==1 means left mouse button
                unselect(ev);
                var dates;
                hoverListener.start(function (cell, origCell) {
                    clearSelection();
                    if (cell && cell.col == origCell.col && !cellIsAllDay(cell)) {
                        var d1 = cellDate(origCell);
                        var d2 = cellDate(cell);
                        dates = [
                        d1,
                        addMinutes(cloneDate(d1), snapMinutes), // calculate minutes depending on
                        selection slot minutes 
                        d2,
                        addMinutes(cloneDate(d2), snapMinutes)
                    ].sort(cmp);
                        renderSlotSelection(dates[0], dates[3]);
                    } else {
                        dates = null;
                    }
                }, ev);
                $(document).one('mouseup', function (ev) {
                    hoverListener.stop();
                    if (dates) {
                        if (+dates[0] == +dates[1]) {
                            reportDayClick(dates[0], false, ev);
                        }
                        reportSelection(dates[0], dates[3], false, ev);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide your actual code to show the issue

Comment: please include the code you've attempted

Comment: Hi Irvin and Wim , I have attached my my jquery code by editing my question. Please take a view of that.